# Should we claim http://meta.apple?

Tags: discussion, meta

I typed in `meta.apple` into chrome, and rather than googling for Ask Different Meta, it tried to load `http://meta.apple` and failed.

Should we claim `http://meta.apple` and have it redirect to `http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/`?

Comment: Is `.apple` even a valid top level domain?

Comment: @patrix I thought it was, based on a quick google search. I could be mistaken. Am I too cynical to think it is valid?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how this would be possible. Apple owns .apple and I doubt they're going to give us a subdomain. Also, I'd presume the main site is more worthwhile for a .apple subdomain than just the meta site.